# Using Localization in a pod

Tags: swift, localization, cocoapods

I have not found any similar topic here. I am developing a pod that requires multi-language support.

I am adding a **Localizable.string** :

this one is for the English version:

```
"No Preview Available" = "Preview is not available for this file";
"No Network Available" = "An error has occurred, please check your network connection or try again later.";
```

and a **class** to handle string localization

```
private class Localizator {

    static let sharedInstance = Localizator()

    lazy var localizableDictionary: NSDictionary! = {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings") {
            return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        fatalError("Localizable file NOT found")
    }()

    func localize(string: String) -> String {
        guard let localizedString = localizableDictionary.value(forKey: string) as? String else {
            assertionFailure("Missing translation for: \(string)")
            return ""
        }
        return localizedString
    }
}

extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return Localizator.sharedInstance.localize(string: self)
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error when I run the project example with my (hereabove) pod as a dependency.

[unable to locate the Localizable file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zizR5.png)

the Localizable file cannot be found.

**How can I make the strings file available in my development pod ?**
Any hint ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your podspec:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
            'YourBundleName' => ['path_to_resource/Internationalization/*.lproj']
        }
```

and refer to this bundle name.